# First name mentions in a text using discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make some sort of kick system. I would like to know how I would get the first name mentioned in a text.

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
if (message.member.hasPermission(["KICK_MEMBERS"],["BAN_MEMBERS"])){
    if(message.content == "!kick"){
        let member = message.mentions.members();
        console.log(member)
        member.kick("You have been kicked").then ((member) => {
        message.channel.send( member.displayName + " has been Kicked!"); 
        })
    }
}
});
```

No error is thrown that I know of.

Comment: Admittedly I'm not familiar with discord.js, but the documentation suggests that [`members()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members) is a **collection** of members, however [`.kick()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kick) is a method of a **single** member. Essentially, your `let member` variable is a *list* of members - you need to select one from the list to kick.

Comment: The original line for it was
let member = message.mentions.members.first();
And it sill didn't work.

Comment: what does `console.log(member)` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if you want to check multiple permissions in [`GuildMember.hasPermission()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission), you need to pass an array. The way your code is written now, you're passing an array with `"KICK_MEMBERS"` as the permissions to check and an array with `"BAN_MEMBERS"` for the `explicit` parameter.
**Solution:** `message.member.hasPermission(["KICK_MEMBERS", "BAN_MEMEBRS"])`

Secondly, you're declaring `member` as a Collection, when it should be a GuildMember.
**Solution:** `const member = message.mentions.members.first()`

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.content === "!kick" && message.member.hasPermission(["KICK_MEMBERS", "BAN_MEMBERS"])) {
    try {
      const member = message.mentions.members.first();
      if (!member) return await message.channel.send(`No user mentioned.`);

      await member.kick(`Kicked by ${message.author.tag}`);
      await message.channel.send(`${member.user.tag} has been kicked.`);
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
});
```